# Console returns none 12 times. There are 12 images. Can images not be scraped?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to build a scraper to get all the listings images from this site. I figured out how to get all the pages into a .txt file, but while trying to do the first page with this code the console spits out none 12 times. Is scraping not allowed?

Also how would I pull the URLs from the .txt file after the first page is scraped and go down the list.

There is 6585 URLs with 12 listings on each page except for the last there is 2.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://irockdecals.com/shop-decals/?sort=bestselling&page=1"

sourceCode = requests.get(url)

plainText = sourceCode.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(plainText, "html.parser")

irock = (soup.find_all('div', class_="card-img-container"))

for img in irock:
    soup.find_all("src")
    bingo = img.get("src")
    print(bingo)
```

Comment: After trying out a few things, I feel bs4 not the correct choice for your requirement, because the images are lazy-loaded, I suggest using selenium or something similar.

Comment: if i get the url to the img src it will be the same file as if i got it from each product page.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is, in lazy-loading, you don't get the actual image URL initially, you get a dummy loader URL when you scrape the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While iterating through div element you need to get the image in each div ('img') and then get 'src' for that image element.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://irockdecals.com/shop-decals/?sort=bestselling&page=1"

sourceCode = requests.get(url)

plainText = sourceCode.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(plainText, "html.parser")

irock = (soup.find_all('div', class_="card-img-container"))

for img in irock:
    image_element = img.find("img")
    bingo = image_element.get("src")
    print(bingo)
```